# How to block a single .js file in ie6?

Tags: javascript, blocking, internet-explorer-6, adblock

Been banging my head on the desk for two hours now. I need to block JUST ONE .js file in ie6 (need to keep JS enabled in the browser):

`http://php.net/ie6update/ie6update.js`

That DARN script breaks my Zend Studio's internal browser or, if I enable JS in ie6, I get a nag popup message every time I look up a function from php.net.

I can't update to ie7,8,9 (long story).

EDIT: Thought about my HOSTS file, no-worky.

Comment: It appears there's no amicable solution. If anyone has any ideas, I'm going to check in on this question regularly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.net uses the annoying `ie6update.js` script. You can block it from displaying with a custom user style sheet.

Create a .css file that contains:

```
#activebar-container { display: none !important; }
```

In Internet Explorer > Tools > Options > [General Tab] > Accessibility, tick the "Format documents using my style sheet" box and select the CSS file you created.

It won't stop the js from running, but you won't see the bar any more.

Answer (score 1):

Head over to `Tools` -> `Internet options`. Click the Privacy tab, under the Privacy window, Click Sites -> Enter `http://php.net/ie6update/ie6update.js` -> Block.

Comment: That didn't work, but it was a good shot. That's for blocking cookies only, not certain scripts. And it's locked to a domain, not a path. =(

Comment: Ouch. HOSTS won't help either, IIRC. Let me see if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Heheh, I was thinking, "maybe there's a plugin or something for ie6 that could help...?" but can't find anything like that.

Comment: I was actually searching for an addon - but I don't think IE6 supports addons. Can't you try some other browser ? Chrome/ Firefox both have portable editions if you cannot install anything.

Comment: I wish I could try another browser, but ie6 is built into Zend Studio and I cannot update my system to ie7,8,9. Looks like I'm stuck for now. =(

Answer (score 0):

You can give the script a class then target that class and change the 'src' attribute to '#'.

```
document.querySelectorAll('script')[0].setAttribute('src', '#');
```